# WCF call WCF - lags

Tags: c#, wcf

Trying Console app hosted WCF service. All be fine, but timings...

WCF at Console app start with code:

```
    ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(DeviceService));

    public void StartServiceHost()
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " ServiceHost is opened");
        host.Open();
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
    }
```

At other WCF service (used for send data to SL App) in method I call this service by code:

```
DeviceCacheService.DeviceServiceClient client = new DeviceCacheService.DeviceServiceClient();
List<Telemetry.Models.Device.DeviceModel> models = client.DEVICE_Get().ToList();
```

When last code create request to first service, next row processed after 3-4 seconds. I tried set breakpoints - between call service method and start ConsoleAppWCF side code processed go by 2-3 seconds.

What I do wrong?

Comment: How many items is in `models` list? What is a size of single item?

Answer (score 0):

Please add any binding information from your app (Server and SL).

That said, psychic debugging indicates that you are using a secure binding that is using Windows authentication. The second guess is that you are not running this machine connected to a domain, so it is taking a little bit of time for the call to get credentials to figure out that the AD controller isn't present.

Even if the machine isn't connected to a domain, WCF calls functions that try to get the Windows credentials as if MACHINEName\UserName had MACHINEName actually being a domain. Once that fails, the code then treats MACHINEName as a machine name. 3-4 seconds is common for this failover.

Of course, I may be way off but I thought I'd take a guess.

Comment: emmmm. Shift+Enter to next row

You mean app.config binding info?

        <services>
          
            <service name="DeviceServer.Services.DeviceService">
                <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="DeviceServer.Services.IDeviceService">
                    <identity>
                        <dns value="localhost"/>
                    </identity>
                </endpoint>
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>